# Shared database across company computers

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've set up a database on my local computer, and also on a server for a website. I'm now faced with the need to set up a database for a company of computers (~50). How would I set this up for this need? I know this is a vague question, but any advice or links would be much appreciated.

Comment: you setup mysql as  you would do normally and you have to Enable Remote Access . but its more complex than that, if you need to scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a vague question, which requires more details to give a better answer, but in short you should procure a server, install a linux distro (I suggest [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/)), and use the built in package manager to install MySQL (yum install mysql). Then you will have to manage users, schema, and timely back-ups, but once you get the ball rolling it's not too bad.

Also, I'd suggest visiting [DBA Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) if you plan to ask more 'vague' questions of this nature.